# One `if`, two `then`s: Why not?

Tags: linux

I want to make a script that adds a space every time it counts up and outputs the number it's at until it gets to 10 then stops. I'm learning scripting and I'm just making simple scripts to learn. Here's what I've made so far:

```
x= 1
if ["$x" < "10"] then
echo [ $x += 1 ]
echo "\n"
then
echo "done!"  
fi
```

Comment: As you can see, there are two `then` and one `if`.  Start with fixing that.  Also, you do not need to enclose `10` in quotes, that will make it a string.  Numbers are compared differently; use `-le` in place of `<`.

Comment: No spaces in variable assignment. Spaces are needed in your tests [ x..... ].

Comment: See: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_09.html <-  There are 11 other chapters you may also find useful ;)

Comment: Ok so i have this: x=1
if ["$x" -le 10] then
echo [ $x += 1 ]
echo "\n"
echo "done!"                                                                                              don                              but it still doesn't work it says "done" unexpected. fi doesn't work either it says its expecting "then"

Comment: Keep in mind this **isn't** a discussion forum, so open ended and evolving threads aren't appropriate.   It's a Q&A format, see [the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).  The conceptual problem you have here is the difference between *branching* (e.g. `if`) and *looping* (e.g. `while`), both of which involve *conditionals* and are generically referred to as forms of *flow control*.

Comment: The line `echo [ $x += 1]` is quite nonsensical in sh syntax so no wonder you're getting strange results. If you want to do arithmetic I suggest you use expr, check the man page. [] is a shorthand syntax for the test command which is probably not what you want in echo.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if`, `then` clause is made up of:

```
if followed by one or more conditions
then
   some actions
fi
some further actions
```

As you can see there is no need to add another `then` to have some further processing to be done. So your case should be:

```
x=1
if [ $x -le 10 ]
then
   echo "$x"
   ((x++))
fi
echo 'Done!'
```

Now you have a working `if`, `then` clause but you will also see that the only thing returned is `1` followed by `Done!`

This is because the `if` statement only checks the condition once and when the `fi` is reached the script goes on with further processing, in this case the `echo 'Done!'`

To have your idea working you should use a `while` loop. A `while` loop checks the condition until it matches:

```
x=1
while [ $x -le 10 ]
do
    echo $x
    ((x++))
done
echo 'Done!'
```

Now the `while` loop is being entered as long as the value in variable `$x` is less than 10. When the condition returns false (value of $x is less or equal to 10) it jumps to the `done` statement and goes on with further processing, in this case the `echo 'Done!'`

Answer (score 0):

Because the computer cannot decide which branch to use! With each `if` you branch on a boolean expression [TRUE/FALSE] to execute some code or not. So each decision requires exactly one action branch to be executed. That's why you just use one `then`.

```
let 'x = 1'
if [ "$x" -lt 10 ] # if you want to write the `then` on the same line you need a ; in front of it
then
    let 'x++'
    echo "$x"
    # echo automatically creates a newline
    # the second then is useless or even wrong
    echo "done!"  
fi
```

also see `help [` in the shell:

```
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

and read `man -s1 test`, to see valid test expressions.

#### Tip

Your expression [ "$x += 1" ] seems to imply that you actually want to loop from 1 to 10. As the shell has only limited arithmetic support you should better use `seq`:

```
for x in `seq 1 9`
do echo $x
done
echo "done!"
```

For very long sequences might be better not to produce an input string for the `for` loop, but read the values one by one:

```
seq 1 1000|while read x
do echo $x
done
```

and check `man 1 printf` and `man 3 printf` (normally written as printf(1) and printf(3), but you told us, that you are a beginner), to add the spaces

```
printf "%*s%s" $x "" "line"
```

adds $x spaces in front of "line".

#### Victory

```
for x in `seq 0 9`
do let 'y=2*(9-x)'
    printf "%*s%s%*s%s\n" $x "" "data" $y "" "data"
done
```

Comment: of course the for loop is always faster as there aren't multiple read calls